# Linq To Sql Entity Framework Getting Nested Entities

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do an include of a nested entity. I assumed the below code would work but it does not recognize the CapitalMailOrders entitycollection. Can anyone point me in the right direction to include these?

```
    var result = db.Contacts
        .Include(a => a.IDXPageLinks)
        .Include(b => b.ReboGatewayLoginInfoes)
        .Include(c => c.SocialMedias)
        .Include(d => d.WebSiteInfoes)
        .Include(e => e.ContactImages)
        .Include(f => f.RealtorSetUpProcesses)
        .Include(h => h.RealtorSetUpProcesses.CapitalMailOrders) // getting compile time error here. Doesn't recognize Entity 
        .Include(g => g.Contact_CarrierCode_Assignments)
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.ContactID == id);
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra entity level is accessed from a collection and so you need to add a Select in order to bring all the entries into the include.

```
.Include(h => h.RealtorSetUpProcesses.Select(h2 => h2.CapitalMailOrders)
```

Comment: Get the error "A specific Include path is not valid. The entity type does not declare a navigation property with the name CapitalMailOrders". I tried it with "RealtorSetUpProcesses.CapitalMailOrders" and it didn't throw any errors but it didn't include the nested collection.

Comment: Does your Contacts entity have a navigation property to RealtorSetupProcesses and does the RealtorSetupProcesses have a navigation property to the CapitalMailOrders?

Comment: Thanks @Phil. That worked. I think the main problem was there was no data in the table. After I added  record and changed to your updated snippet I was able to look at the collection. Thanks again.